# regarding toupper() using pointer arithmetic

Tags: c, pointers, increment

I am facing an interesting issue while trying to understand toupper() function. Please find the code below: 
Issue here is in the output I am **missing** the first character of my input string always.

Please correct my mistake. I am posting this after doing too much of google about this.

```
void UpperString()
{

    char arr [10];
    memset(arr, 0x00, sizeof(arr));
    strcpy(arr, "abcd");
    char *ptr = arr;
    char *temp = ptr;
    printf("Before Upper String - %s\n",ptr);
    while(*ptr++ = toupper(*ptr))
    {
        printf("ptr - %s\n",ptr);
        printf("FULL - %s\n",temp);
    }
    printf("After Upper String - %s\n",temp);
    return;
} // UpperString()
```

**Output**

```
Before Upper String - abcd
ptr - bcd
FULL - Bbcd
ptr - cd
FULL - BCcd
ptr - d
FULL - BCDd
After Upper String - BCD
```

Comment: I think you have undefined behavior in `*ptr++ = toupper(*ptr)`: You're reading from `ptr` (in `*ptr`, the function argument) and you're modifying `ptr` (in `ptr++`), and there's no sequence point in between.

Comment: This code is goog in rivalisation between C programmers, but bau i normal code which shold have well controlled effect. Too much operations inline in the same place

Answer (score 1):

```
while(*ptr++ = toupper(*ptr))
```

This line has problem . You tend to change value of `ptr` more than one time in a single execution line ,thus invoking *undefined behaviour*.

> C99 §6.5: “2. Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression. Furthermore, the prior value shall be read only to determine the value to be stored.”

Increment in another line .

```
while(*ptr= toupper(*ptr)){
// your code
...
ptr++;
```

}

Comment: Hey Amey, thanks for your reply. I got your point but how the same code is working as expected in one processor but not in others

Comment: @sakthi You mean it work on one system and not on other ? That maybe side effect of undefined behaviour . In **UB** output can be anything maybe even my phone number :)

Answer (score 0):

You ask about understanding toupper(), but the problem in your code has nothing to do with this function.

```
while(*ptr++
```

`*p++` has sense "value from addres & increment ptr after work", so used cell if the first nr 0), but PTR is incremented

`toupper(*ptr))` 
right side read a letter from already advanced pointer, 'b', make 'B' and will set in cell `a`

Here is same code without that problem:

```
void UpperString()
{

   char arr [10];
   memset(arr, 0x00, sizeof(arr));
   strcpy(arr, "abcd");
   char *ptr = arr;
   char *temp = ptr;
   printf("Before Upper String - %s\n",ptr);
   while(*ptr = toupper(*ptr))
   {
      printf("ptr - %s\n",ptr);
      printf("FULL - %s\n",temp);
      ptr++;
   }
   printf("After Upper String - %s\n",temp);
  return;
}
```

Comment: why down? tell precise if You have charges

Comment: Your English is barely comprehensible, and the explanation you gave is wrong: C does not evaluate expressions from left to right.

Comment: maybe evaluation order is importable (between compilers), but how you describe exchange a i b

Comment: ... I don't understand what you just wrote.

Comment: @melpomene maybe code is more international :) If C code is buggy and/or unreadable dismount whistles

Comment: I agree, order of expression is maybe un-specyfied, to tell in human words, what do CPU in 10uS is impossible.

Comment: Yes, sometimes I have received corrected records and better, thanks. I'm old programmer but systematic English teaching was poor in times when I go to scool

Answer (score 0):

The rule in C is that same variable should be modified only once in one single operation and used only to determine previous value. Reference: 6.5 Expressions §2 in draft n1256 for C99: *Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value
modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression. Furthermore, the prior value
shall be read only to determine the value to be stored*

In same statement, you change the value of `ptr` but also use it in `toupper(*ptr)`: the two operation are not sequenced and you get undefined behaviour.

You should write:

```
while(*ptr = toupper(*ptr)) /* Ok ptr is unchanged, and *ptr is read to compute value to store */
{
    printf("ptr - %s\n",ptr);
    printf("FULL - %s\n",temp);
    ptr += 1;   /* Ok ptr is changed here but not use elsewhere */
}
```